# Sphinx "words" on result

Tags: python, sphinx, words

i run query with text "test for test" ...
and got result from sphinxapi (python) in list words:

`'words': [{'docs': 281, 'hits': 340, 'word': 't230'},
2011-10-11 19:42:06+0600 [-]             {'docs': 4396, 'hits': 6317, 'word': 'a53'},
2011-10-11 19:42:06+0600 [-]             {'docs': 2453, 'hits': 2917, 'word': 'f60'}]}]`

how get "normal" words?

Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" words?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late but "t230" seems to be the [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) version of "test".

In section `index { ... }` of your sphinx.conf file, check if the `morphology` contains the value `soundex`.

If you comment the `morphology` line (setting it by default to `none`) and reindex, you'll see that the `words` will display what you're typing.

Note that changing the morphology will impact the way Sphinx indexes your documentation and your search results will/may be different.